# How to partition pandas data frame based on week and save as CSV?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas data frame as below. This data frame about one month period.  How do I partition this data frame based on week? I need save each 4 weeks as seperate 4 CSV files.

```
Time Stamp              Id  Latitude    Longitude
01/10/2016 15:22:51:700 1      23        50
01/10/2016 16:28:08:026 1      23        50
01/10/2016 16:28:09:026 1      12        45
02/10/2016 19:00:08:026 2      23        50
02/10/2016 20:28:08:026 1      23        50
03/10/2016 19:00:08:000 2      23        50
03/10/2016 01:02:33:123 2      23        50
03/10/2016 06:15:08:500 1      23        50
03/10/2016 10:01:07:022 3      28        88
......
......
31/10/2016 13:09:17:044 1      33        80
```

My expected output is:

```
Time Stamp              Id  Latitude    Longitude
01/10/2016 15:22:51:700 1      23        50
01/10/2016 16:28:08:026 1      23        50
01/10/2016 16:28:09:026 1      12        45
02/10/2016 19:00:08:026 2      23        50
02/10/2016 20:28:08:026 1      23        50
03/10/2016 19:00:08:000 2      23        50
03/10/2016 01:02:33:123 2      23        50
03/10/2016 06:15:08:500 1      23        50
03/10/2016 10:01:07:022 3      28        88
......
......
07/10/2016 03:09:10:066 5      28        78
```

This should be my first week. Next weeks from 08/10/2016 to 14/10/2017, from 15/10/2016 to 21/10/2017 and from 22/10/2016 to 31/10/2017.

Answer (score 2):

You can convert column first to `datetime`s and then to `year-weekofyear` by [`strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html).

Last loop `groupby` and call [`to_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_csv.html):

```
ts = pd.to_datetime(df['Time Stamp'], format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S:%f').dt.strftime('%Y-%W')

for i, x in df.groupby(ts):
   x.to_csv('{}.csv'.format(i), index=False)
```

Comment: Thanks Jezreal for the answer. But when I save it as csv I got only one day (31-10-2016 ...............) data. (I got only all the rows belongs to this day). At least if I could separate those 4 week as 4 different data frames, that also fine. Because I need to calculate time difference between two consecutive events.

Comment: Are data confidental? Because if not, can you send it to my email in my profile? Thanks.

Comment: Really appreciate your kind help. But data are confidential Jezreal.

Comment: OK, is possible data anonymize? Or only get column with datetimes, another columns can be removed? thanks.

Comment: I just found a way to create different DF according to the answers you gave me for another question. Thanks and we can't even share as anonomized data too. Thanks again!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `Time Stamp` is of `datetime` dtype:

```
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='Time Stamp', freq='W')) \
  .apply(lambda x: x.to_csv(r"/path/to/{}W{}.csv".format(x.name.year,x.name.week)))
```