# Pyspark: memory error when saving a sql.dataframe

Tags: pyspark

I have a `pyspark.sql.DataFrame` that I would like to save as `.csv`. This is what I am doing.

```
df.toPandas().to_csv('myDF.csv')
```

Is it possible to partition the data in different chunks and save them as separate files?

Comment: you can refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48150346/how-to-partition-pandas-data-frame-based-on-week-and-save-as-csv

Comment: why you are converting to pandas(which is giving the memory exception), instead you can directly write, df.write.csv('myDF.csv')

Comment: @RangaVure thanks I will try in that different way. I thought that step was necessary

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this using below

```
df.repartition()
df.coalesce(<integer value to number of file you want>).write.csv()
```

do not convert spark dataframe to pandas, directly save it to file.

Comment: I have this error `TypeError: repartition() missing 1 required positional argument: 'numPartitions'`

Comment: df.repartition(100).write.csv()